# Is there any difference on building apk in Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, android-signing

I have issue. First I was use Windows10. I change my mind 1 years later and I using ubuntu. I building app-debug.apk in Ubuntu but not work on my devices. I encounter with two error Sometimes block by play protect, sometimes the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name. But when i open Windows10 and building app-debug.apk there is no issue  Have you ever solution this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the instant run in android studio. It causes lot of errors.

Comment: I build app-debug.apk and send device memory and installing apk file from device file manager. I am not running from android studio